# What's a "Lie type"?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to understand what's meant by "Lie type" in the paper "Character degrees and random walks in finite groups of Lie type" by Liebeck and Shalev, available [here](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Emwl/chardeg3.pdf). Several theorems involve statements such as "fix a (possibly twisted) Lie type $L$'' (Thm 1.1).

What is a Lie type? Examples from the paper include things like $L = L_2$, $F_4$, or $^2F_2$. It is also clear that a Lie type has an associated Coxeter number $h$.

I'm not a finite group or Lie theorist, but I know that there is a connection to root systems. I understand these to be a certain kind of finite geometric/combinatorial object. Do root systems have some axiomatization such that they precisely correspond to Lie types $L$ of quasisimple finite group, as used in this paper? If the story is complicated as I suspect it is, efficient references would be helpful.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type, https://mathoverflow.net/q/136880/27465.